# Setting commandtext clears added params on SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql

If I add parameters to sqlcommand object (addwithvalue) and afterwords I set another commandtext it will erase previous params ?
example (example code):

```
string sqltest = "some query col1=@param1 AND col2=@param2";
sqlcommandobject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1",sqldbtype.whatever).value=somevar;
sqlcommandobject.commandtext="other query but with also @param1";
//it will erease the previous addwithvalue?
```

Comment: What did your tests point out?

Comment: What is the question here? If parameters are removed from command when you change commandtext? If this is the question then answer is no. You have to clear them from command object. sqlcommandobject.Parameters.Clear();

Comment: I need to be sure because it will be a lot of coding and hours spent. And it's on-line deployment :( . So I asked if anyone already got stuck on this doubt and already know the answer.

Comment: It is trivial to create a unit test or small application to test things. You should really favor that approach over asking people online.

Comment: thank you shukri gashi. you can put your reply.